# Tensorflow r1.2 c++ api error when using libtensorflow.so

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a code that was working perfectly fine with r1.1.

I am trying to run the code in different computer. So installed Tensorflow r1.2 from sources. I first build libtensorflow.so, and link it to my executable. Now I am getting thousand errors like:

`undefined reference to 'tensorflow::internal::LogMessageFatal::`

It seems like libtensorflow.so is built at all. I used the command

```
sudo bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --copt="-mtune=native" --copt="-O3" tensorflow:libtensorflow.so --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone
```

to build libtensorflow.so. I also tried r1.1 with the same computer and it works fine. What was changed in r1.2?